# Why is my background image not displaying in IE?

Tags: html, css

I've been designing a website with Wordpress and began doing testing in different browsers, and I discovered, frustratingly, that the main background image of my header is not displaying in IE9, IE8, or IE7 - and most probably, not in IE6 either.

I am relatively new to CSS, and cannot figure out what the problem is. I've been searching *many* help topics and forums, and haven't found the answer to my particular issue, so if someone would please kindly help me, I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Here's the link to the site: http://www.godlygirlhood.org/sandbox

Here's the CSS code for the header:

```
#branding {
    width: 1015px;
    height: 559px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: #f2e9b3;
    background-image: url(http://godlygirlhood.org/sandbox/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/GG-header_1015px.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: It's displaying fine for me. Make sure that you clear your cache and temp files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the HTML5 header tag which is not supported in versions of IE older than 9. You can add support for the tag by using a polyfill script like Modernizr or change the header tag to a div

Comment: I don't mean to sound dumb, but how do I do that, @GeoffWarren?  Thank you for helping.

Comment: You would either have to edit the html to change the tag or check out [modernizr.com](http://modernizr.com/) for instructions on how to implement the polyfill.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those options out!

Comment: I will once, I figure it all out.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It's displaying fine for me in IE9. Try clearing your cache and see if that fixes it. It could just be a caching issue.

Comment: I had a friend check it out with IE9, and he said it didn't display, but perhaps it is now...but not it's showing - despite clearing the cache - in my IE7.  Thank you, though!

Comment: Sorry for the confusion: I do not have IE9.  My friend does, and he said previously it had not been displaying.  After his feedback, I then found some code which might have been the problem and fixed it, so that may be why it is now showing in IE9.  But it is not displaying my IE7, despite my CSS fix.

Answer (score 0):

Based off of @GeoffWarren's advice and subsequent research, I discovered a Wordpress plug-in to easily take care all HTML5 tags which are not supported in IE8 and lower: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/html5shiv/  For those who are using WP and experiencing similar difficulties with the header tag, this will quickly solve the problem.

Thanks, @GeoffWarren and @JamesJohnson for your suggestions and help.